# Java coding- a prompt with multiple right answers

Tags: java, string, if-statement, input

So I'm incredibly new to Java and coding in general. I've been asked to code a program that asks the user a riddle and responds with "Correct!" or "Wrong!" depending on the answer. I thought an `if else if` statement would do the trick but it is not returning the desired results. the answers `"man"` or `"a man"` are both considered correct (and capitalization does not matter Ex "mAn" would still be right, but "man!" would not).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("What walks on four legs in the morning, two legs in the afternoon, and three legs in the evening? ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Answer = input.next();

        if(Answer.equals("man"))
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong!");

        if (Answer.equals("a man"))
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
}
```

Comment: One of your issues might be that `input.next()` only retrieves a single word.  So if the user types `"a man"`, the variable will be set to `"a"`.  You'll want to use `input.nextLine()` instead.  You might also like to think about using `else` and `if` together on the same line.

Comment: If case doesn't matter you should use `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: Have you studied the boolean operation `||` (or) yet? And have you studied `else if`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here. First, `next()` only reads util the closest whitespace, so if `"a man"` is an acceptable answer, you should use `nextLine()` instead.

Second, if the case of the answer is not an issue (e.g., `"man"`, `"Man"` and `"mAn"` are all correct), you should handle it. There are several ways of doing it, but the easiest would probably be to convert the inputted answer to lower case before evaluating it.

Third, if the answer isn't `"man"`, your `else` clause will print `"Wrong!"`, even if the answer isn't. One way to solve this is to use an `else if` clause instead:

```
String answer = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

if (answer.equals("man")) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else if (answer.equals("a man")) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

But and even neater way would be to simply use the logical `||` ("or") operator:

```
String answer = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

if (answer.equals("man") || answer.equals("a man")) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I was confused as to why it was only accepting "man" as the correct answer. I really appreciate your help; I completely forgot about the || operator! Ill revise my work with your input in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `input.next()` with `input.nextLine()`

'input.next()' is whitespace delimited i.e. it "stops" after it finds a "space" character in your input string.

**Edit:** Your conditional logic is also flawed, for example if you input "a man" you are getting a wrong message before a correct one.

Get rid of that first "else" statement. Better even, combine the two correct conditions into one if check using OR.